# Using a data structure to solve this in O(n)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

we have sequence of 4 characters (A,B,C and D)that map to numbers form 1 to n.
we define components to be:

```
Component(k) :
A {cell[k]}
if Color(left_k) = Color(k)
then
    A <-- A U Component(left_k)
if Color(right_k) = Color(k)
then
    A <-- A U Component(left_k)
return A
```

there is 3 types of operations(the numbers in list indicate the input):

1. by giving index it should remove the component in that index(the numbers mapping to characters are fixed)

   example : AABBBDA is the string. if index is 3 it should return AADA
2. by giving index it should rotate the string based on the component on that index(the numbers mapping to characters are fixed)

   example : AABBBDA is the string. if index is 3 it should return DABBBAA
3. it should print the string.

inputs are like:

```
1 2 --> first operation with index=2
2 3 --> second operation with index=3
3 --> third operation
```

It's an assignment, happy to get help.

---

this is what i've tried so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int numberOfOps;
    String[] print = new String[30];
    List list = new List();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = input.nextInt();
    String colors = new String();
    colors = input.next();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        list.add(colors.charAt(i));
    }
    numberOfOps = input.nextInt();
    list.printElement();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfOps; i++) 
    {
        int op = input.nextInt();
        if(op == 1)
        {
            int index = input.nextInt();
            char c = list.item[index];
            int temp = index;
            int prevIndex = index;
            int nexIndex = index;
            if(index != 0)
            {
                while (list.item[--index] == c)
                {
                    prevIndex--;
                }
                while (list.item[++temp] == c)
                {
                    nexIndex++;
                }
                list.setNext(prevIndex-1, nexIndex+1);
            }
            else
            {
                while (list.item[++temp] == c)
                {
                    nexIndex++;
                }
                list.setNext(prevIndex, nexIndex+1);
            }

        }
        if(op == 2)
        {
            int index = input.nextInt();
        }
        if(op == 3)
        {
            print[i] = list.printElement();
        }
    }

}
```

here is my List class:

```
public class List {
// reference to linked list of items
public static final int MAX_LIST = 20;
public static final int NULL = -1;
public char item[] = new char[MAX_LIST];  // data
public int avail;
public int next[] = new int[MAX_LIST];       // pointer to next item
private int numItems; // number of items in list
public List() 
{
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < MAX_LIST-1; index++)
        next[index] = index + 1;
    next[MAX_LIST-1] = NULL;
    numItems = 0;
    avail = 0;
}  // end default constructor
public void add(char e)
{
    item[avail] = e;
    avail = next[avail];
    numItems++;
}
public String printElement()
{
    String temp = null;
    int index = 0;
    while(index<avail)
    {
        temp += item[index];
        System.out.println(item[index]);
        index = next[index];
    }
    return temp;
}
public int size() 
{  
    return numItems;
}  

public void setNext(int i, int value)
{
    next[i] = value;
}
}
```

if you test it you'll get, it has lots of problems, such as, I have no idea to do the rotate operation, and it has problem with connecting two components when the middle component has been removed.

Comment: I think of using linked lists.

Comment: if I understand that correctly, if the same letter is used in sequence, that sequence is taken as one "big" component (in your example, BBB and AA is always used together)? And indexing begin from 1? (first letter is at index 1)?

Comment: @libik yes, that is correct. and indexing is from 1.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? It's hard to give specific advice otherwise ...

Comment: @user3478966 - When DanielB asked what you had tried, he meant what actual code you had written.  Just thinking about it isn't trying.  Bear in mind that this is >>YOUR<< assignment, not ours.

Comment: @StephenC my attempt has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult question to answer, because the requirements are not properly stated.

For example the first bunch of pseudo-code does not make it clear whether `A` is a set, a multi-set or a list.  The notation (use of curly brackets, and U (union?)) seems to say set ... but the output seems to be a list.  Or maybe it is supposed to be a schema for a data structure??

And even the inputs are not clearly described.

---

But putting that on one side, there is still room for some (hopefully) helpful advice.

1. Make sure that >>you<< understand the requirements.  (I imagine that the real requirements for the assignment are better stated than this, and the details have been "lost in translation".)
2. I would actually use an array list (or a StringBuilder) rather than a linked list for this.  (But a properly implemented linked list ... implementing the `List` API ... would work.)
3. But whatever data structure you chose, there is no point in implementing it from scratch ... unless you are *specifically required* to do that.  There are perfectly good list classes in the Java standard libraries.  You should reuse them ... rather than attempting to reinvent the wheel (and doing a bad job).
4. If you *are* required to implement your own data structure type, then your current attempt is a mess.  It looks like a hybrid between an array list and a linked list ... and doesn't succeed in being either.  (For example, a decent array list implementation does not need a `MAX_LIST`, and doesn't have `next` pointers / indexes.  And a linked list does not have any arrays inside it.)

Comment: As I mentioned in question, A is a data structure, and yes you are correct, the assignment is about linked list, and I'm required to implement the structure!

Comment: @user3478966 - 1) The question does NOT say that A is a data structure.  Read what you wrote!  2) In that case, I suggest that you throw away your `List` class, and start again.  A simple linked list should consist of nodes, where each node has a `value` field and a `next` field.  No arrays.

Comment: you are right, sorry for that mistake ;)I used this implementation because there is also a number(n) witch maps to every character, I used array index to be that number(also it's fixed)

Comment: @user3478966 - And that brings us back to my original problem with your Question.  I don't understand your requirements, and apparently nobody else does.  Unless you can do something about that, I don't think I can be of any further help. Sorry.